# How to disable conventions in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm using SQLite with EFCore, but I got a problem... how can I disable Conventions like Pluralize? Is it possible?

My ModelBuilder has not a property Conventions...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             modelBuilder. [NOT HAS PROPERTY CONVENTION]
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837617/where-are-entity-framework-core-conventions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable pluralizing naming convention as shown below.

```cs
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ModelBuilder RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (entityType.ClrType == null)
                continue;

            entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.ClrType.Name;
        }

        return modelBuilder;
    }
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No! It's not possible in ef core. as @Mustafa told, you can override convention by fluent API configuration.